# Credenciales de wordpress no estan funcionando en wp admin (local)

Tags: wordpress

Realize una migracion y tratando de ingresar al wp-admin de un sitio local de wordpress con las credenciales correctas no me esta dejando ingresar. [image: Tratando de acceder al localhost]

Comment: Abre `wp-config.php` y revisa que la base de datos que esté en `DB_NAME`, sea la correcta. Si es así, haz un `SELECT * FROM wp_users` y revisa que tu usuario esté allí.

Comment: Esa clave es de prueba y no del sitio real verdad??

Comment: El wp-config ya lo cheque y si enlaza de manera correcta, y ya revise el usuario y esta ahi con la misma contraseña @javdromero

Comment: Y si es clave de prueba la real es otra del sitio @OCHOA

Comment: "y esta ahi con la misma contraseña " Recuerda que la clave que ves en mysql está encriptada, entonces no es lo que debes de digitar en el login. Estoy dudando que sea tu sitio.